# Is there a way to export a TeeChart to PDF?

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

I've created a TeeChart in RAD Studio XE8 C++ Builder. I know you can use Print or PrintPartial to output to a printer. I'm wondering if there's a way to output this TeeChart to a PDF?

edit:
This feature is included in the "pro" version. For now, I'm using the TeeChart Draw function to draw to a bitmap, then use a separate utility to move that into a PDF.

Comment: Just found out it's part of the Pro version. Is there a way to do this via BitBlt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TeeSaveToPDFFile function to export a chart and create a pdf document with it. Ie:

**.h:**

```
#include <VCLTee.Series.hpp>
#include <VCLTee.TeePDFCanvas.hpp>
```

**.cpp:**

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  TBarSeries *Series1 = new TBarSeries(Chart1);
  Chart1->AddSeries(Series1);
  Series1->FillSampleValues();

  TeeSaveToPDFFile(Chart1, "C://tmp//testCBuilder.pdf");
}
```

Another alternative is to use a virtual pdf printer and print the chart to it.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, however Builder can't find VCLTee.TeePDFCanvas.hpp. Is this only in certain versions of TeeChart?

Comment: Looks like that's part of the Pro version.

Answer (score 1):

I've exported charts (not from TeeChart, but similar) to PDF using Libharu. You can save your image as png (or bmp) to stream or file, and then load using Libharu and draw on the page.

Here is the documentation:
[Libharu Wiki](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki)

See functions in **API: Document**, for example **HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile()**

If you need, I can write the code that loads the png image from hard drive and prints it on a PDF page.